# how to install mysql drivers for php7 on windows system

Tags: php, mysql, composer-php, php-7

How to install MySQL drivers for php 7 on windows system?

[image]

> Error: - Installation request for pear-pear.php.net/mdb2_driver_mysql 1.4.1 -> satisfiable by pear-pear.php.net/MDB2_Driver_mysql[1.4.1].
>    - pear-pear.php.net/MDB2_Driver_mysql 1.4.1 requires ext-mysql * 
>   -> the requested PHP extension mysql is missing from your system.
>
> Problem 2 - Installation request for pear-pear.php.net/validate_au 0.1.4 -> satisfiable by pear-pear.php.net/Validate_AU[0.1.4].
>    - pear-pear.php.net/Validate_AU 0.1.4 requires php >=4.2.0.0,<=6.0.0.0 -> your PHP version (7.1.4) does not satisfy that requirement

Comment: please re-upload the image

Comment: @RakibulIslam A low-rep user is not allowed to upload images. But you are allowed to edit the post!

Comment: Error:
    - Installation request for pear-pear.php.net/mdb2_driver_mysql 1.4.1 -> sati
sfiable by pear-pear.php.net/MDB2_Driver_mysql[1.4.1].
    - pear-pear.php.net/MDB2_Driver_mysql 1.4.1 requires ext-mysql * -> the requ
ested PHP extension mysql is missing from your system.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for pear-pear.php.net/validate_au 0.1.4 -> satisfiabl
e by pear-pear.php.net/Validate_AU[0.1.4].
    - pear-pear.php.net/Validate_AU 0.1.4 requires php >=4.2.0.0,<=6.0.0.0 -> yo
ur PHP version (7.1.4) does not satisfy that requirement.

Comment: @RakibulIslam. This really shouldn't be an image at all.

Comment: @TRiG Why did you mention me? I'm not the OP. May be you had done some mistake. :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

PHP7 does not have the mysql_ database extension any more. Its dead Jim

Answer (score 2):

I guess you haven't enabled mysql in your XAMPP server yet. To do that:

At first close all running services of xampp. Now, go to your `xampp` folder. Then go to `php` folder and open the file named `php.ini` with any text editor. Now search for `mysql` in that file. You will find a line stating `;extension=php_mysqli.dll`. The `;` symbol describes it as a comment that means it is not enabled yet. Simply cut out that `;` sign in front of that line which will now look like `extension=php_mysqli.dll`. Finally save the file and restart xampp.

Comment: Thanks for your response. however the line uncommented and mysqli is loaded properly. for composer installation and for other things i would want mysql drivers to be installed

Comment: PHP7 does not have the `mysql_` database extension any more. ___Its dead Jim___

Comment: -Does this mean oven for cake php error : 'Mysql driver is not available' is valid with PHP7, and if so how can it be patched up with sqli perhaps?

Comment: You really saved me !...Thanks a lot Bro !